# How do I configure Postfix to send emails with ProtonMail Bridge?

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 server and I followed this tutorial to install ProtonMail Bridge :

https://pychao.com/2020/06/10/update-on-using-protonmail-bridge-on-headless-wordpress-linux-servers/

> The reason ProtonMail users require this extra utility is that, for
> outbound emails, ProtonMail encrypts users’ email content before
> handing over the email to the sending server. And for inbound emails,
> ProtonMail decrypts the email contents for users after downloading the
> emails, and so when users open the incoming emails, the contents are
> readable. While using ProtonMail’s online interface, everything is
> done behind the scene. Users just write/read emails as they do on
> Gmail, etc. But if users want to use offline email clients on their
> local machines, then those clients lack the functionality of
> encrypting/decrypting the emails before/after doing communications
> with ProtonMail’s servers (see note 1). That’s why ProtonMail provides
> a utility called Bridge.
>
> In a nutshell, ProtonMail Bridge creates fake IMAP/SMTP servers on the
> local machine. And users use these fake local servers for the
> IMAP/SMTP settings in their offline email clients. When offline
> clients try to do communications with email servers, they are in fact
> communicating with the fake local servers. And next, the local servers
> do the encryption/decryption tasks and then talk to the real
> ProtonMail servers.
>
> For more details, please read the introductions at ProtonMai Bridge.
> This post does not intend to deal with the usage of Bridge. Instead,
> this post tries to deal with an issue that occurs when using Bridge in
> headless (i.e., not connected to any physical monitors) Linux
> environments.

I have a Drupal 8 site on my server and it is sending emails correctly with ProtonMail Bridge.

Now I want Postfix to use ProtonMail Bridge to send server emails (Logwatch, Monit, ...).

I followed the following tutorial to install and configure Postfix :

https://devanswers.co/configure-postfix-to-use-gmail-smtp-on-ubuntu-16-04-digitalocean-droplet/

**Here is my configuration**

Install Postfix

```
$ sudo apt install postfix
```

*Enter the domain mydomain.com at "System mail name" and leave the rest by default*

Configure Postfix

```
$ sudo nano /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

...

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = ov-hjhjhjhj.kjkjkjj.ch
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, mydomaine.com, ov-b2bbd0.infomaniak.ch, localhost.infomaniak.ch, localhost
relayhost = [127.0.0.1]:1025
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
```

Create the sasl_passwd file to store the credentials

```
$ sudo nano /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

...

```
[127.0.0.1]:1025 contact@mydomaine.com:password
```

*Use information in ProtonMail Bridge*

Create a hash database file

```
$ sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

Secure credentials

```
$ sudo chown root:root /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db
$ sudo chmod 0600 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db
```

Restart Postfix

```
$ sudo systemctl restart postfix
```

Check status Postfix

```
$ sudo systemctl status postfix
```

Install mailutils

```
$ sudo apt install mailutils
```

Test sending email

```
$ echo "Contenu du mail" | mail -s "Titre du mail" contact@mydomaine2.fr -aFrom:contact@mydomaine.com
```

The problem is that I am not receiving any email and there is no error message. What is wrong with my setup ?

Here is the Drupal 8 configuration that works :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOlCL.png)

Comment: Check your mail server logs.

Comment: For starters you have either omitted lines from your `main.cf` file or haven't followed the tutorial at https://devanswers.co/configure-postfix-to-use-gmail-smtp-on-ubuntu-16-04-digitalocean-droplet/ because there are no `smtp_...` lines in your config so your `sasl_passwd` file is not being referenced anywhere.  Second, you are telling postfix to send mail to port 1025 on the same machine (`localhost`) - what is listening on that port?

Comment: @tetech No, I haven't forgotten anything, it's ProtonMail Bridge listening on the port. Yes it is locally, you must read the following article to understand how the Bridge works https://pychao.com/2018/10/13/use-protonmail-bridge-on-headless-linux-machines/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have omitted the lines telling postfix to authenticate when sending mail, which were in the postfix tutorial you cited.  Thus your `sasl_passwd` file is ignored.

At least you should have

```
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
```

if these are not already in `master.cf`.  However, you should reproduce the relevant lines from the mail log to accurately diagnose the problem, otherwise everything is guesswork.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But there are 2 problems. 1) The emails are sent in duplicate. 2) You have to put `all` instead `loopback-only`, is that normal ?

Comment: 1) Check mail logs to see what is going on there. 2) `inet_interfaces` should not need `all` but maybe `$myhostname, localhost` in case the connection is made using the public IP/hostname.  Disallow external connections via firewall.

Comment: I don't see the problem, here are the logs, the first email sent is received in duplicate and the second is not received https://pastebin.com/qPk3wLFf

Comment: Each of the two messages is being handed off from postfix to your "ProtonMail Bridge", that is the `250 Ok: queued`.  Any deliverability issues after that should be due to ProtonMail or your incoming mail server, rather than postfix at the sending end.